# WebDriverjs - Selecting from dynamic menu

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, webdriver

Using webdriverjs, I want to automate clicking a div element (sub-menu in html page) whose innerHTML is known to me. The ids of the div elements(submenus) are dynamically generated, so i cannot rely on them to access the div.

For Example, I know 'Item 2' which is the innerHTML of the target div

```
<frame id='A'>
    <frame id ='B'>
        <div class='menuitem' id='dynamicid1'>Item 1</div>
        <div class='menuitem' id='dynamicid2'>Item 2</div>
    </frame>
</frame>
```

I have written the code as

```
driver.switchTo().frame('A');
driver.switchTo().frame('B');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("//div[text()='Item 1')]")).click();
```

But the intended click does not seem to happen.

Any help is going to be useful for me.

Comment: Try clicking on the element without switching to frame(s). I think, probably it isn't necessary. And, since it's a sub-menu as you say, first click on the menu item, then proceed with clicking on the submenu item using your last line of code above.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work.